# Why do class-based OO-languages always use the keyword `new` to create an object?

Tags: object-oriented, programming-languages

I do not know much about OO-languages, but from what I have seen, it seems most class-based OO-languages uses a keyword `new` (or something equivalent) to create an object. Prototype-based OO-languages like JavaScript even fake it.

From a viewpoint of keeping the syntax simple, why not leave out the `new` keyword and use only the constructor (typically of the same name as the class)?

Is there any semantic consideration involved in prefixing the constructor with a `new` keyword?

I have noticed that in Scala, if you define a `case`-class, you can simply use the constructor without a preceding `new` to create an object, while for other classes, you have to use `new`. I do not know the reason. I mention it simply because it may be related.

Comment: Did you have a look at Python? It works exactly the way you suggested - without the new keyword. I guess most languages using "new" as a keyword just inherited that from C++ for historical reasons.

Comment: In Delphi / Object Pascal you call the constructor directly: myClass := TMyClass.Create;

Comment: In C++ and JavaScript it's syntactically important. But even in languages where it could have been left out, don't you think it makes for more descriptive (self-documenting) code?  If I write `List()` is it creating a list, or is it listing something (noun or verb)? If I write `new List()` the ambiguity goes away.

Comment: In Java, it is possible for class X to contain a method X that cannot be distinguished by its parameter list from an X constructor. "new" distinguishes object creation from method invocation.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I guess you could avoid that with explicit `this`, couldn't you? I think "new distinguishes object creation from method invocation" is exactly the point, though... not necessarily just for the compiler/interpreter, but also for the developer.

Comment: @Hey: Which leads to the obvious question: why should object creation be distinct from method invocation? `List()` is a terrible name for a method.

Comment: Why would anyone ever want a non-constructor function that looks like a constructor?

Comment: @DeadMG Why is List a terrible name for a method (other than annoying StudlyCaps)? If I have something like an "AuctionItem" and I want to *list* it at auction, what should I call that action? Whether object creation and method invocation should be separate is good question. In languages like Lua I sometimes write a function that creates objects and I always find myself wanting to write `new` unless I name it like `createFoo`. Just two different ways of looking at the same problem I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's simply a question of C++ having this syntax (and it needed some syntax because the language was not strong enough to support implementing `new T();` at that time as a library) and then inherited. From memory, Java inherited it from C++, JavaScript picked it up from Java, and so did C#. Since then, it seems to have become pretty standard.

Fundamentally, it's no different to using curly braces to denote scope- it was inherited from a common ancestor.